# How to pass data value from one Child Component to another Child Component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Weather project where I have two components. One for day/night timings: `SunriseSunset` and another for daily forecast: `DailyForecast`. I need to pass value of time obtained from `SunriseSunset` to `DailyForecast`.

Here are the two components for reference:

1. SunriseSunset.js (First File) --> Function Component

```
const SunriseSunset = (props) => {

    const time2  = moment.tz(props.timezone).format('HH:mm')

   // I want to pass the time2 value in DailyForecast.js file
    
    return (
        <React.Fragment>

        
        </React.Fragment>
    ) 
}



export default SunriseSunset
```

2. DailyForecast.js (Second File) --> Class Component

```
export class DailyForecast extends Component { 

        return ( 
            <div>
            
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DailyForecast
```

Comment: Is `DailyForecast` a successor or nested child of `SunriseSunset`?

Comment: `props` are made for that, you could use React Context API to pass data between components too.

Comment: @im_tsm Its not nested child, both  are siblings

Comment: All right, but they share a common parent right?

Comment: @im_tsm yes right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should lift the shared state/data up to common ancestor. Here is a working
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-cloud-rhbtv?file=/src/App.js) example.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";
  const time2 = moment.tz(timezone).format("HH:mm");

  return (
    <>
      <SunriseSunset time={time2} />
      <br />
      <DailyForecast time={time2} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the official documentation: [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Also, if you don't want to drill down props on multiple levels then you should consider [React context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or something like Redux for managing application state. Redux is a robust state container but it might be overkill for your use case.

Comment: I actually solved on my own... but, even this is useful for me... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. The first question you need to ask yourself is do these two child components have the same parent?

you need to pass values from SunriseSunset to the same parent of DailyForecast and then when the parent gets the value it needs to pass the value down to DailyForecast;(you can also use context api to do it in a simpler way)

2. You can use third-party state management library like redux to construct a isolated state.

And then you need to make SunriseSunset and DailyForecast have access to this isolated state. after that these child components are able to share states;(there are so many state management libraries like Mobx, or state-machine)

3. There are also other options if you do not want any of the above solutions.
   Just use local storage or url to share your states.

For instance, in SunriseSunset you can save this state in localstorage or url and in DailyForecast you can read this state from the current url or localstorage. But this option is not elegant.

Comment: Yes, local storage is not an ideal use case for this scenario. We should use local storage only when we need the data to be persisted over page refresh(which is application reset/re-run). Also, just to mention, you have to write side-effects(`useEffect`) to read from or write into local storage.